# Can I set up conditional scheduled tasks in R?

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I have 2 questions about scheduling a task:

1. I would like to schedule a task to run on the first business day at 12pm every month. Is it possible to do so?
2. If the first run doesnt produce a file, a second task will be scheduled to run at the end of that day.

Comment: What type of machine are you hoping to run it on. See if this helps: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html https://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/64-scheduling-r-scripts-and-processes-on-windows-and-unix-linux

Comment: Just my normal laptop with windows

Comment: try the `taskscheduleR` works for me